# How does the exact phrase query in MongoDB work in conjunction with additional words?

Tags: mongodb

From the [tutorial section about exact phrase queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#exact-phrase):

> For example, the following will find all documents containing “java” or “coffee shop”:
>   `db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "java \"coffee shop\"" } } )`

However, when I run it, it only returns the one store called "Coffee Shop". Why doesn't it return the two documents with "java" in their `name` field: "Java Hut" and "Java Shopping", that you `insert` at [the beginning of the example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#example)?

Comment: Because it is the exact designed behavior as specified in ["Phrases"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) in the documentation. *"If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match the documents that include the phrase. More specifically, the search performs a logical AND of the phrase with the individual terms in the search string."* So there is no such thing as an "OR" whilst using a "phrase".

Comment: @NeilLunn: first off, that contradicts the tutorial explanation. Moreover, if the search performs such a "logical AND", then it shouldn't match "Coffee Shop", that does match the phrase but doesn't match the additional term "java". Here's the document it returns: `{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Coffee Shop", "description" : "Just coffee" }`.

Comment: No it does not contradict at all and is in fact the direct quotation from the documentation, which also goes on to quote: *"For example, passed a $search string: `"\"ssl certificate\" authority key"` The $text operator searches for the phrase "ssl certificate" and ("authority" or "key" or "ssl" or "certificate" )."*. So it is actually all documented right where I linked you to. You should actually read it.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Your link does explain why "Coffee Shop" is returned (thanks), but the language of the tutorial still contradicts your link. It states "the following will find all documents containing “java” or “coffee shop”". In reality, it will only return documents containing "coffee shop" (though they may also contain "java"). In fact, I'm not sure what's the purpose of including additional terms in this situation, since it seems the query will return all documents containing the phrase, and the presence of the other terms makes no difference.

Comment: To be more "blunt", a search on `"java shop"` returns both the `"java coffee shop"` and `"java shopping"` ranked by **best match** on `"shop"` just like it should. When you ask for the "Phrase" of `"\"Coffee Shop\""` then you are actually getting **exactly what you asked for** since there only is **one** document that matches such a condition. Works as designed. The documentation really is not the problem here, but rather your interpretation. But if you look more closely, everything does clearly work exactly as described.

Comment: @NeilLunn: I understand, but in that case, what is the point of adding more terms to a query that includes a phrase?  Either way, you'll get all the documents that contain the phrase, and none that don't. The added terms make no difference.

Comment: I don't see this as being productive. You misinterpreted the documentation and you have been corrected on that. I see neither a question or issue beyond that. If you think the documentation needs to be different, then submit a patch to MongoDB with your suggestions. But "works as designed" is the response here.

Comment: The tutorial example you've cited has an error that will be addressed ([DOCS-10382](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10382) in the MongoDB issue tracker). However, I think there may also be an implementation issue. The expected outcome is described in the [Phrases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases) section of the `$text` docs, but unless I'm missing something this translates into logic that ignores additional positive terms outside the phrase search (as you have suggested). A more useful outcome would use additional terms to further refine the matches.

Comment: I couldn't find a [MongoDB SERVER issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/issues/?jql=component%20%3D%20%22Text%20Search%22%20AND%20project%20%3D%20SERVER) describing a related improvement to the phrase search matching. If you'd like, you can raise an improvement suggestion directly at https://jira.mongodb.org (project: SERVER, component: "Text Search"). Otherwise I'll raise one after looking into the issue a bit further.

Comment: @Stennie: thanks!  I created the [SERVER-30163](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30163) issue per your instructions, to address the functionality problem. The DOCS-10382
indeed describes the present documentation bug in the manual, though I believe it makes a lot of sense to change the behavior to match the one described in the manual, which is more sensible, consistent, and useful than the current behavior.